# Problem with autowiring RegistryInterface in ServiceEntityRepository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I was following Symfony docs and wanted to use `ServiceEntityRepository` ([link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository)).

I created entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BetRepository")
 */
class Bet
{
....
```

Repository was automatically created:

```
namespace App\Repository;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use App\Entity\Bet;

class BetRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Bet::class);
    }
}
```

I wanted to create `BetService` which uses `BetRepository`:

```
namespace App\Service;
use App\Repository\BetRepository;

final class BetService
{
     private $betRepository;

     public function __construct(BetRepository $betRepository)
     {
           $this->betRepository = $betRepository;
     }
```

finally I created a controller and wanted to inject `BetService` into it:

```
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Service\BetService;

final class BetController extends AbstractController
{
    private $betService;

    public function __construct(BetService $betService)
    {
        $this->betService = $betService;
    }
}
```

Problem is I keep getting error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\BetRepository": argument
>   "$registry" of method "__construct()" references interface
>   "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface" but no such service
>   exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

my services.yaml is default one from installation:
    parameters:

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    public: false

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

# controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I am using Symfony 4.2

I tried autowiring `EntityManager` to `BetRepository` however I get error that `EntityManager` constructor is not public and tbh I feel this is not the right approach as docs say it should work out of box.

I can provide composer.json (didn't initially as already question is quite long)

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Please verify you have use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface; in your BetRepository class.  Pretty sure you do but your posted code does not show it.

Comment: @Cerad yes I do ... Sorry for sloppy copy pasting.

Comment: Do a "bin/console debug:container | grep Registry" from a console window.  (You might need to comment out some code to get past your current error).  But you should have a "RegistryInterface alias for doctrine" line.  Can't imagine why you would not unless you started with just the skeleton and did not require the orm-pack.

Comment: @Cerad yes something is wrong with that. I just noticed a lot of .yaml files are missing from config and I don't have RegistryInterface alias for doctrine" in this project as I have in some other I was learning on. Will debug further and report.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I made a fresh 4.3.2 install and your code seems to work fine.  Might be time to start fresh.

Comment: Yes you are right. There wasn't much progress and I will catch up to the point I am now relatively fast. Please if you'd like make an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Maybe not relevant for your issue, but `RegistryInterface` has been deprecated in `DoctrineBridge` (v4.4) and has been replaced with `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` in MakerBundle 1.13.

Comment: hey @msg thanks for the tip. Project since moved forward and it looking pretty good. Yeah I just checked and new version is out for 2 days. I will make sure to update dependency and this deprecation.